# How to set ComboBox display and value member when DataSource is List<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, data-binding, combobox

I've got a problem with display and value member settings of `ComboBox`. `DataSource` I'm using for is list of dynamics. Code looks like this:

**.NET**

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
{
    _List = Massive.DB.Current.Query("EXEC cboPlaces").ToList<dynamic>();
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
{
    cboPlaces.DataSource = _List;
    cboPlaces.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cboPlaces.ValueMember = "ID";
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**SQL stored procedure (cboPlaces)**

```
SELECT ID, Name, PostNumber, Region
FROM dbo.Places
ORDER BY Name
```

I used to create list of Place objects with members ID, Name and this way of setting display and value member worked properly. However, it's not working when I get list of dynamic objects directly from database table using stored procedure. Name and ID are select values inside my stored procedure so I thought it should work this way. The error I'm getting is:

```
ArgumentException unhandled by user:
Cannot bind to the new display member.
Parameter name: newDisplayMember
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:**

I have changed the order of setting `ComboBox` properties from

```
cboPlaces.DataSource = _List;
cboPlaces.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboPlaces.ValueMember = "ID";
```

to

```
cboPlaces.ValueMember = "ID";
cboPlaces.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboPlaces.DataSource = _List;
```

I'm no longer getting an error, but display member is *System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject* instead of the name of the place even though I can see all values I got from database through debugger. Any suggestion?

**NOTE:** This works just fine with WPF.. too bad we don't use it..

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but using Name as the name for anything is not always a good idea. Can you try changing `SELECT ID, Name,..` to `SELECT ID, Name as theName,..` or the like?

Comment: I think you can use format event to display the appropriate value. I'll try tomorrow, till then you can try this link and see if this can work for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format

Comment: @TaW It's not actually the name of that column. Actual name is more complex and less readable, I'm just trying to get to the point, but I found out that binding dynamic objects as datasource in Windows Forms is casually causing troubles.. :(

Comment: @pushpraj I'd love to see your solution. If possible I also need to be able to get value member when saving combobox value inside my other class. Other posts I found online are suggesting to avoid binding ExpandoObject to the datasource, because it's far too complex. I don't have much experience with it though so any suggestion is welcome.